# Animated superhero parody with humanoid snail antagonist and a pursuit scene

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

I have been trying to identify an animated TV show of which I saw a couple episodes as a kid, probably around 2010. It was likely a parody (or at least comedy) of the superhero genre. The main character was superhero or special agent kind of character. I think he had a number of gadgets, but don't remember exactly which. At some point he may have used something like a stink bomb. I am not sure whether he also had any supernatural special powers.

In one of the episodes, there was a humanoid snail character, that I think was the main antagonist of the episode. He was human-sized and had a human face (like older? man), but his body was build like a big land snail (although I think he had hands) and he had a shell on his back. I am not sure why the MC was after him, perhaps he suspected him of something, or was trying to thwart some evil scheme?

There was a rather hilarious "stealthy" pursuit scene, where the main character was driving his car and tailing the snail across the city, but the snail was moving at a typical snail's pace, so the MC had to match his speed. I also think the MC wasn't very subtle, driving his car only few meters behind the snail (perhaps as a parody of such scenes in police procedural shows).

In another scene, the humanoid snail was eating in a posh (French?) restaurant and he ate some food made from snails (e.g. something like [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/Escargots_3.jpg) WARNING: gross image of French cuisine linked, do not view while eating). Eventually, the MC followed him to the restaurant and they talked. Then there might have been a fight scene against the antagonist's henchmen. I don't remember much of the rest of the episode. There might have been a twist in the end, like the MC falsely suspecting the snail of crime, or being forced to work with him, but I may be mixing things up with some other show.

I think it was a parody/comedy based on the above. And I also have a feeling there was something funny/lame about the main character, like he had some lame power or silly superhero name. It was set in a contemporary city and I think most of the characters were humans (i.e. humanoid characters like the snail were not common).

I tried to write everything I could remember, but my memory of it is very hazy and it is likely I misremembered some details, so don't get discouraged if you have at least a partial match. The snail pursuit scene is what I am most confident about.

Comment: Can I click the gross image link while I'm eating snail with garlic butter?

Comment: @Clockwork go ahead :D that warning was not aimed at French cuisine enthusiasts. But I know viewing that during lunch would make me lose my appetite.

Comment: @vogrick I would hesitate to dismiss escargots with garlic butter as gross food. They're actually pretty tasty and make a good first course.

Comment: @Nzall Oh I was more trying to point out that it may not be _visually_ appealing to everyone. I wrote that remark partly as a joke, I hope I didn't insult anyone - I have nothing against French cuisine (I never ate a snail though). Also the scene was far less "graphic" with the depiction of the food than I remembered.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is almost definitely episode #12 of [*Rat-Man*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rat-Man_(comics)#Animated_series), an Italian animated series first aired in 2008 sharing the main characters (but little else) with the Italian comic having the same name.

The [whole series](https://www.raiplay.it/programmi/rat-man) is freely available on the site of the Italian public broadcasting company, no registration needed.

I think every detail you remember matches:

- while the comic, besides being hilarious, also has darker and more serious themes, the animated series is aimed at kids and its tone is mainly comedic / parodic
- the main character is a "super hero" in name only, as he does not posses any supernatural power, physical fitness or cunning
- even his name is a caricature of Batman's, just like many gadgets of his and other details like Rat-Man's butler that appears in some episodes

---

The Snail-Man falling on Rat-Man while he is (not) eating *escargot* in a French restaurant:

[image: Snail-Man falling on Rat-Man]

Rat-Man in his super car slowly following the Snail-Man:

[image: Rat-Man in his super car slowly following the Snail-Man]

Comment: Thanks that was it. As expected my memory of the episode was pretty bad.

Comment: Also I am pretty sure it had English dubbing, but the only versions I could find were either the original Italian dub or Tamil language dub. I will have to try to find the English dub or at least subtitles, because I don't speak Italian.